# How to dasherize filter URL sent by Ember query?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to learn Ember by developing a simple TODO manager application.

I am using ember-data and JSONAPISerializer with a hand rolled REST JSON API backend for this application.

I have the following model which represents a task

***app/model/task.js***

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr ('string'),
    description: DS.attr ('string'),
    isComplete: DS.attr ('boolean')
});
```

The corresponding JSON data from backend looks like this

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "1",
        "type": "task",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "Complete Ember TODO manager application",
            "description": "Build a simple Ember application for easily managing tasks",
            "is-complete": "false"
        }
    }]
}
```

As per the convention, the Ember model uses camel cased names and the JSON API backend uses dasherized names.

A basic feature in this application is to filter tasks by their status, so basically one can see either ongoing or completed or all tasks.

For fetching only the ongoing tasks, I have the following query in the model hook of the corresponding route

***app/routes/tasks/ongoing.js***

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model () {
        return this.get('store').query('task', {
            filter: {
                isComplete: 'false'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So when the query is sent to the backend it goes as

```
restjsonapi/tasks?filter[isComplete]=false
```

The problem is that the backend expects "is-completed" and does not understand "isComplete".

Is there a way to dasherize the URL emitted by Ember query?

### Edit (possible workaround):

I might have been trying to solve this the wrong way I think. I have changed the JSON data to have underscores instead of dashes and worked around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `store.query`, Ember then finds the relevant adapter for your model type and calls `adapter.query` which in turn seems to pass your query to `jQuery.ajax` as a value for the `data` attribute. See here: 
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.7.0/addon/adapters/rest.js#L504

The conversion from Object to Query String is then done by jQuery using `encodeURIComponent` as you can see there: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e4fd41f8fa4190fbbb6cb98cf7ace64f6e00685d/src/serialize.js#L68

So you won't be able to change this behaviour by passing an option to Ember.

However, you could try something like:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model () {
        return this.get('store').query('task', {
            filter: {
                "is-complete": 'false'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And it should work.

Comment: I feel dumb now knowing how simple that was. Thanks Nazim!